# Formatting currency when exporting amCharts

Tags: format, export, xlsx, amcharts

I'm working with amCharts 3.20.9, I sucesfully draw a graph and may export the data into an XLSX file. However, one of the columns I'm exporting is a currency, is there a way of setting such a format in the resulting file?

The script I have for the graph is:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("graph", {
        "type" : "serial",
        "theme" : "light",
        "dataProvider" : data,
        "valueAxes" : [ {
            "stackType": "regular",
            "gridColor" : "#FFFFFF",
            "gridAlpha" : 0.2,
            "dashLength" : 0,
            "title" : "Metros cúbicos"
        } ],
        "gridAboveGraphs" : true,
        "startDuration" : 1,
        "graphs" : graphs,
        "chartCursor" : {
            "categoryBalloonEnabled" : false,
            "cursorAlpha" : 0,
            "zoomable" : false
        },
        "categoryField" : "formatedTime",
        "categoryAxis" : {
            "gridPosition" : "start",
            "gridAlpha" : 0,
            "tickPosition" : "start",
            "tickLength" : 20,
            "parseDates" : false,
            "labelsEnabled": true,
            "labelFrequency": 3
        },
        "export" : {
            "enabled" : true,
            "fileName" : "Reporte",
            "exportTitles" : true,
            "exportFields" : fields,
            "columnNames" : columnNames,
            "menu" : [ {
                "class" : "export-main",
                "menu" : [ "PDF", "XLSX" ]
            } ]
        }
    });
```

Where:

graphs contains the graphs definitions, something like:

```
[{
                    "balloonText" : "[[formatedTime]]: <b>[[" + sites[i] + "]]</b>",
                    "balloonFunction" : formater,
                    "lineThickness": 1,
                    "lineAlpha" : 0.2,
                    "type" : "line",
                    "valueField" : sites[i]
            }];
```

fields: ["formatedTime", "Viva Villavicencio", "Viva Villavicencio_COST_"]

columnNames: {"formatedTime": "Fecha", "Viva Villavicencio": "Metros cúbicos para: Viva Villavicencio", "Viva Villavicencio_COST_": "Costo para: Viva Villavicencio"}

So far so good, I have my xlsx with the proper data, but at the end I want the column "Viva Villavicencio_COST_" be defined as a currency in the resulting file and therefore formatted and displayed that way.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `processData` option. It takes a callback function that lets you make changes to your dataset before it gets written to your exported file.

So, add to your code:

```
"export": {
  "processData": function(data){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
      data[i].Viva Villavicencio_COST_ = toCurrency(data[i].Viva Villavicencio_COST_);
    }
    return data;
  }
  ...
}
```

This function returns the exact dataset as before, but with a formatted `Viva Villavicencio_COST_` field.

Then, add the function `toCurrency`. I don't believe amCharts has a function built in for formatting. If you need a better formatting function you could use something like `numeral.js` or `accounting.js`, but for now try:

```
function toCurrency(value){
  return '$' + value;
}
```

Complete docs for the export plugin are here: https://github.com/amcharts/export

Hope that helps.